# Why does ssh prompt me every time for the passphrase when ssh-agent is running?

Tags: lubuntu, ssh, ssh-agent

After reinstalling Lubuntu Vivid Vervet on my computer, whenever I try to `ssh` into something, it asks for my passphrase. Before the reinstall, it would give me a graphical prompt for my passphrase if I had not done that in the session yet. Now, it asks me for the passphrase every time.

ssh-agent is running, and if I run `ssh-add`, it saves my key for the session.

If you need logs, please comment where they would be.

Comment: I think what you mean is it used to ask you to open the keyring containing your passphrase (graphical prompt) and now it asks you for the actual passphrase each time. If so, check if you're using any key managers like gnome keyring manager (you can run it on LXDE, I think it's called `seahorse`), maybe it got uninstalled for some reason.